# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell

Tags: java, mysql, excel

I have seen lot of answers over here regarding my question, but can not find solution for it. I am reading a excel file and storing in mysql database. This is my code

```
            Sheet mySheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            for (Row row : mySheet) {
                int columnNumber = mySheet.getFirstRowNum();
                Cell c = row.getCell(columnNumber);
                String sql = "insert into medtest(FMCODE,FLAG,MCODE,EMPNO,NAME,ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2,ADDRESS3,BALANCE,HOSPITAL_O,HOSPITAL_I,NURSING,GENERAL,PRIVATE,SPLCODE,BKCD,ACCOUNT_NO) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) con
                        .prepareStatement(sql); 
                ps.setString(1, row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
                ps.setString(2, row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
                ps.setInt(3, (int) row.getCell(2).getNumericCellValue());
                if (c != null) {
                if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                    ps.setString(4, row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue());
                else if(c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
                    ps.setInt(4, (int) row.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue());
                }
                ps.setString(5, row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
                ps.setString(6, row.getCell(5).getStringCellValue());
                ps.setString(7, row.getCell(6).getStringCellValue());
                ps.setString(8, row.getCell(7).getStringCellValue());
                ps.setFloat(9, (float) row.getCell(8).getNumericCellValue());
                ps.setFloat(10, (float) row.getCell(9).getNumericCellValue());
                ps.setFloat(11, (float) row.getCell(10).getNumericCellValue());
                ps.setFloat(12, (float) row.getCell(11).getNumericCellValue());
                ps.setFloat(13, (float) row.getCell(12).getNumericCellValue());
                ps.setFloat(14, (float) row.getCell(13).getNumericCellValue());
                ps.setString(15, row.getCell(14).getStringCellValue());
                ps.setString(16, row.getCell(15).getStringCellValue());
                ps.setString(17, row.getCell(16).getStringCellValue());
                ps.executeUpdate(); 
            }
```

The below is my exception occuring at line `ps.setString(4, row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue());`

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.typeMismatch(HSSFCell.java:643)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.getRichStringCellValue(HSSFCell.java:720)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.getStringCellValue(HSSFCell.java:703)
    at org.stc.action.DataImport.doGet(DataImport.java:94)
    at org.stc.action.DataImport.doPost(DataImport.java:70)
```

The cell contains of both string and integer values

1.Sample data : D05 (String)

2.Sample data : 3916(Integer)

But in my table i have taken varchar as its datatype

Comment: can you attach your excel sheet or a screenshot of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to check the type of the returned cell:

```
if (row.getCell(3).getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) 
   ps.setString(4, row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue());
else 
   ps.setString(4, String.valueOf(row.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue()))
```

Comment: I have changed and run it, showing 'Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell'

Comment: reverse of the exception

Comment: @spt Sorry my fault. See my updated answer. You have to check the cell at index 3 not at index 0

Answer (score 0):

Write a helper method, I had similar issue, sometimes even though you expect string (or int cell) they are of different type if they are empty:

```
if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
{
 //process string value
}
else if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
{
 //process numeric value
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: are you running all cells of all rows through this method? I had an issue where in one column some cells were text some were numeric.

Comment: only particular cell which has text and integer values i.e , once check my code ps.setString(4,getType)

Comment: you still have ps.setString(4, row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue());
above the check, did you forget to edit or it's still in the code?

Comment: change ps.setString(4, row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue()); 
 ps.setString(4, c.getStringCellValue()); (just to make sure you're reading correct cell). Show the stack trace with these changes.